# Alchemy-Websockets - WebSocketClient throws a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, websocket

I have two C# programs that should communicate over WebSockets the server is working perfectly (also using Alchemy) and has been for a while now (with javascript clients). However connecting an Alchemy `WebSocketClient` results in an `NullReferenceException` being thrown on the client side.

After some debugging I found that the exception is thrown on line 187 of [`WebSocketClient.cs`](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets/blob/master/src/Alchemy/WebSocketClient.cs) because of the `_context.Connection.Connected` call. The _context.Connection is the same instance as the local `_client` and neither of those are null at that point in time. On the `TcpClient.Connected` page on msdn.microsoft.com there are no possible exceptions listed (indicating to me that it shouldn't throw any exceptions).

Going further back I noticed that the `_client` class variable is changed on line 176 of [`WebSocketClient.cs`](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets/blob/master/src/Alchemy/WebSocketClient.cs) from a normal looking instance to an instance filled with exceptions:

**BEFORE LINE 176**
[image: Before line 176]

**AFTER LINE 176**
[image: After line 176]

Right after this line the Dispose() method of the `Context` that was just added on line 187 gets called disconnecting the `Connection` (which is the same instance as the `_client` that I mentioned before on line 131 of [`Context.cs`](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets/blob/master/src/Alchemy/Classes/Context.cs).

My question is: Why is this happening and how can I stop it from happening and successfully connect to the desired WebSocketServer?

If you need any more information please don't hesitate to ask me in the comments.

**EDIT 1**

The exception only occurs when the server is actually listening, if the server is inactive line 176 of [`WebSocketClient.cs`](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets/blob/master/src/Alchemy/WebSocketClient.cs) is not reached (this is the correct behavior because `OnRunClient()` is called when the connection to the server is made).

**EDIT 2**

As requested the StackTrace:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.get_Connected()
       at Alchemy.WebSocketClient.SetupContext(Context context) in C:\...\Alchemy\WebSocketClient.cs:regel 187
       at Alchemy.WebSocketClient.HandleClientThread() in C:\...\Alchemy\WebSocketClient.cs:regel 94
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: post the code of the before the error happens

Comment: It's all in the WebSocketClient.cs and Context.cs files (the mentions of these files are links in the question above). I have not changed these files in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you use TcpClient. This class uses Socket class for data transfer (TcpClient has such field). As far as I know in some cases this field can be null. 
Property Connected of TcpClient uses Connected property of inner Socket instance. Something like this:

```
public bool Connected 
{
    get 
    {
         return _socket.Connected; // Possible NullRef here!!!
    }
}
```

So when this field is null you will get NullReferenceException. As far as I know this might happen when connection was not successfully established.

For example I see this in your code:

```
try
{
     _client.EndConnect(result);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Disconnect();
     connectError = true;
}

using (_context = new Context(null, _client))
{
      _context = new Context(null, _client);
      _context.BufferSize = 512;
      // some code
}
```

If connection goes wrong you will get an exception and will do some actions, but in this case your _client will have not initialized Socket field inside. In Context constructor you will try to use it field (in Connected property) and you will get NullReferenceException.

I guess you need to add return in catch block.

OR

Check underlying property Client of your TcpClient (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.client(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
if (_client.Client != null && _client.Connected)
{
    // do what you need
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I know how to check if the client is connected/null, the thing I need to know is how to stop this from happening all toghether.

Comment: @dragon112 Sorry, I don't understand you now. I wrote about 2 weak points. The first is that `TcpClient` is written with some "specific" code (and reflector agreed with me) and we can't do anything with it, we can only use workarounds. And the seconds that you create `Context` whether connection was successful or not (why?), this is odd, but you can fix it.

Comment: Oh, I see. I took a look at the code one more time and I found it weak in some parts. This classes definitely need to be fixed. That's all I can say.